# function objects and constructors

Tags: c++

I was just reading [this](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/3-2.html)

```
class biggerThan 
      {
        public:
        const int testValue;
        biggerThan(int x) : testValue(x) { }

        bool operator()(int val) const 
        { return val > testValue; }
  };
```

Now say its used like

```
  std::list<int>::iterator firstBig =
     std::find_if(aList.begin(), aList.end(), biggerThan(12));
```

OR

Just simply like this 
biggerThan object(12)

Now when biggerThan(12) this is used it can invoke the constrcutor to initialze the testvalue or () operator is overloaded and 12 is passed to the function(bool operator()(int val) const ) so that it returns a bool.

which one happens first/how does it works

does it leads to any ambiguity or does the call to the overlaode operator happens in some fashion like

**object.operator().(12).**

please make my undersatnding clear.

Comment: […](http://example.com) What?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe [the following code](http://ideone.com/BT6vt) will make it clear:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class biggerThan 
      {
        public:
        const int testValue;
        biggerThan(int x) : testValue(x) { 
            std::cout << "Construction of biggerThan object with value " 
                      << x << std::endl;
        }

        bool operator()(int val) const 
        { 
            if (val > testValue) {
                std::cout << val << " is bigger than " << testValue 
                          << std::endl;
                return true;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << val << " is *not* bigger than " << testValue 
                          << std::endl;
                return false;
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    int data[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::for_each(data, data+10, biggerThan(4));
}
```

The output is:

```
Construction of biggerThan object with value 4
0 is *not* bigger than 4
1 is *not* bigger than 4
2 is *not* bigger than 4
3 is *not* bigger than 4
4 is *not* bigger than 4
5 is bigger than 4
6 is bigger than 4
7 is bigger than 4
8 is bigger than 4
9 is bigger than 4
```

What happens:

1. The last argument to `std::for_each` is an object of type `biggerThan`, that is constructed with the argument `4`.
2. The `operator()(int)` of this `biggerThan`-object (actually a copy of it) is invoked for every element in `data`.

The algorithm you use (`std::find_if`) works the same in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

> when `biggerThan(12)` this is used it can invoke the constructor to initialize the `testvalue`

Yes.  `biggerThan(12)` creates an instance of the `biggerThan` class with `testvalue` set to 12.

When `std::find_if()` calls the functor, it will call the `operator()(int val)` member function of that instance.

Answer (score 2):

`biggerThan(12)` will pass an object of biggerThan at `std::find_if(aList.begin(), aList.end(), biggerThan(12));` line;

To invoke operator() following is the way;

```
biggerThan obj(12); //This is a constructor call
biggerThan(13); //This is function operator call
```

@`std::find_if(aList.begin(), aList.end(), biggerThan(12));`  the third parameter that is passed will be `temporary object of biggerThan initialized with 12`

Comment: mayank, biggerThan obj(12); won't invake the operator right.....I am asking because i thought it would

Comment: operator() or any other operator comes into picture when an object is created. The operator is called like a function for eg. `obj.operator()(12)`. For this to happen, an object is required on which can invoke some operator/function

Comment: hmm...so operator() is hidden usually while calling while the call actually like obj.operator()(12)....thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can accomplish the same thing using greater<> and bind2nd<>, which are in <functional>

```
list<int>::iterator firstBig = find_if(aList.begin(), aList.end,
                                       bind2nd(greater<int>(), 12));
```

bind2nd turns any binary function object, like greater<int> into a unary function object. In the case of greater<int> it effectively creates a function object whose less than operator looks like this

```
 bool operator>(const int& arg)
 {
    return functor.operator>(arg, 12); 
 }
```

where functor is greater<int>